# Where to enter oAuth in Netbeans to deploy application on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans

After finishing my project, I have right clicked on my project in order to deploy it on Google App Engine. In the available option when I clicked on "Deploy To Google App Engine" It is redirecting me to a browser asking some permissions. When I accept it, it ends up with a page with some token with a message that **"Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:"**

At the same time in Netbeans console I am seeing the error

```
.Please enter code: Either the access code is invalid or the OAuth token is revoked.Details: invalid_grant
```

I did not get any popup to enter the authentication token I got from Google.

Where to enter this code ?

I am using Netbeans 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I just deployed from the terminal using the update exec found in the App Engine SDK bin directory (Java App Engine).

So my command was:

```
$ ./appcfg.sh update ~/Development/path_to_app
```

This way you may enter the authcode into the terminal. Afterwards you should be able to deploy via NetBeans (make sure you have set email and password in NetBeans).

Comment: Any other suggestions on this one? I'm on netbeans 8.2 same issue no idea where to put the command above either...

Comment: @Kdean571 Are you on Windows or Linux? In Windows I believe you should have an appcfg.cmd file in the /bin directory. For example C:\Users\user\Downloads\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.17\bin . You should be able to open a command prompt window here and use the update command: appcfg.cmd update "C:/path/to/app/directory/"

Comment: I'm on Windows...navigated to that folder it opens the cmd prompt but closes before i get chance to read/type any commands..cloud SDK shell executes fine but keep getting java.illegal arg exception expectied command then a list of commands appear...

Comment: Should add this runs fine on local host...so looking at the errors its the specific syntax with the update command thats causing issues

Comment: @Kdean571 I just tried it on Windows and it works fine: appengine-java-sdk-1.9.4\bin>appcfg update "C:\Development\my_app\web"

Answer (score 0):

I Just had this issue couple of days ago.
Excuse me if I do not explain it right, just let me know it is my first post.

To solve it, you would need to run the `cmd`. Go to start and run `cmd`.

Navigate to `C:\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.17\bin` or whichever your appengine location is then type:

`appcfg update "C:/path/to/app/directory/"`

then it will run and show you the place to put the code.
For example:

```
C:\Ali\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27\bin>appcfg update "C:\Users\almiskea\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication5\web"
Please enter code:
```

after you put it, this will show up:

```
Reading application configuration data...

Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Created staging directory at: C:\Users\almiskea\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7644042675237095331.tmp
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.
20% Scanning files on local disk.
25% Initiating update.
28% Cloning 13 application files.
40% Uploading 4 files.
52% Uploaded 1 files.
61% Uploaded 2 files.
68% Uploaded 3 files.
73% Uploaded 4 files.
77% Initializing precompilation...
80% Sending batch containing 4 file(s) totaling 5KB.
90% Deploying new version.
95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
98% Uploading index definitions.

Update for module default completed successfully.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

Then  your application is deployed.